# Combinations of keys in Minecraft do not work reliably

Tags: 18.04, minecraft, keys

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to sprint in Minecraft repeatedly within a timeframe of ~5 seconds, the game might sometimes fail to register one of the sprints.

This does not happen on Windows 10.

I've installed Minecraft using the official `.deb` package available on their website, so it's running natively.

There appears to be no key binding for the combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in my system, I have checked using the command:

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu! We're gonna need some more info in order to help you. Does Mincraft run natively or do you use Wine ( or similar )? Can you run your program from the command line and look for any kind of error output and edit your question to include this info? Thanks :)